# Looping through files in folder successfully but all files print corrupted error

Tags: vba, ms-word, vba7

This code is supposed to open all files in the subfolders of my target
folder and search them for specific terms, print those terms and where
they were found in a text file. If it encounters an error, print that
error so we know which documents to search manually.

It seems to be working, it's finding the search terms in the
documents, but then it prints an error message for each file in the
subfolder that it's corrupted? These files are fine to open, btw. They
don't appear to be corrupted in any way. They do have tracked changes
on, could that be why? I've included some sample output for one folder
below the code.

**FINAL CODE: thanks so much everyone for your help**

```
    Option Explicit

Sub CheckCrossRef()

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim masterFolder As folder
    Dim allSubfolders As Folders
    Dim currSubfolder As folder
    Dim subfolderFiles As Files
    Dim currFile As File
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Dim leftChar As String
    
    Dim strFolder   As String
    Dim strDoc      As String
    Dim wordApp     As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc     As Word.Document
    Dim nameArchive As Word.Document
    
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set nameArchive = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
    
    Dim fd          As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fd
        .Title = "Select the folder that contains the documents."
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            MsgBox "You did Not Select the folder that contains the documents."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set masterFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
    Set allSubfolders = masterFolder.subFolders

    
    For Each currSubfolder In allSubfolders
        
        Set subfolderFiles = currSubfolder.Files
        
        For Each currFile In subfolderFiles
            On Error GoTo errorProcess
            leftChar = Left(currFile.Name, 1)
            If leftChar <> "~" Then
            Set wordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(currFile.Path)
            
            With wordDoc
                Dim SearchTerm As String, i As Long, fileName As String
                Dim Rng As Range, Doc As Document, RngOut As Range
                Dim searchTerms As Variant
                fileName = currFile.Name
                searchTerms = [removed]
                For i = LBound(searchTerms) To UBound(searchTerms)
                    
                    SearchTerm = searchTerms(i)
                    
                    With ActiveDocument.Range
                        With .Find
                            .ClearFormatting
                            .Text = SearchTerm
                            .Forward = True
                            .Wrap = wdFindStop
                            .MatchWildcards = True
                            .Execute
                        End With
                        If .Find.Found Then
                            Dim valueFound As String
                            Do While .Find.Found
                                Set Rng = .Duplicate
                                valueFound = Rng.Text
                                nameArchive.Activate
                                ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
                                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                                Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf & valueFound & "," & fileName
                                
                                wordDoc.Activate
                                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                                .Find.Execute
                            Loop
                            
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            End With
            wordDoc.Close
            End If
nextIteration:
        Next currFile
        
    Next
    
    Dim newPath
    newPath = FSO.BuildPath(masterFolder.Path, "SpecList.txt")
    nameArchive.SaveAs2 fileName:=newPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
    nameArchive.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    
    Set FSO = Nothing
    valueFound = "null"
    Set Rng = Nothing
    Set masterFolder = Nothing
    Set allSubfolders = Nothing
    Set currSubfolder = Nothing
    Set subfolderFiles = Nothing
    Set currFile = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
errorProcess:
    nameArchive.Activate
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Not currFile Is Nothing Then
            fileName = currFile.Name
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf & fileName & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
            
        Else
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    Resume nextIteration
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Some greatly abbreviated output:

1. 03100,03100 Concrete Formwork.docx
2. 05501,03200 Concrete Reinforcement.docx
3. 07920,03251 Concrete Joints.docx
4. 03600,03300 Cast in Place Concrete.docx

---

1. ~$100 Concrete Formwork.docx - 5792 The file appears to be corrupted.
2. ~$200 Concrete Reinforcement.docx - 5792 The file appears to be corrupted.
3. ~$251 Concrete Joints.docx - 5792 The file appears to be corrupted.
4. ~$300 Cast in Place Concrete.docx - 5792 The file appears to be corrupted.

Any advice? Also if you see any other mistakes in the code feel free
to correct. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem right: `For Each currFile In currFile`.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` on the top of the module and sort any errors you'll get.

Comment: `If Err.Number < 0` should be `If Err.Number <> 0`  ?

Comment: @KostasK. thanks, updated the code. You were right, unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams very weird, it is correct in my code? Must have been a formatting thing with stack, haven't changed the error handler in ages. Updated the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~$100 Concrete Formwork.docx
~$200 Concrete Reinforcement.docx
```

These look like the "lock" file which Word generates when someone has a file open for editing. It's not an actual Word file, so you should maybe consider excluding any files which begin with a tilde.

Comment: That was it, thanks so much! Updated code in the post in case it will help anyone